# how to run nohup when prompted for password and/or input parameter

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, nohup

I typically use `nohup` like so:

```
nohup ./myscript.sh 11111 > nohup.out &
```

Where 11111 is an input parameter. In this case, the application is prompting for a password and I'm unable to use nohup.

How do I get around this if I'm prompted for a password? as well as passing an input parameter?  I need the nohup.out for review.

Comment: Wrap it in expect

Comment: Do you have an example how to use expect?

Comment: I think check if autoexpect program is available to you, then you can run autoexpect and the interactive script you wanted to run. That will generate the expect script needed.

Answer (score 1):

try **nohup bash -c "./myscript.sh 11111" > nohup.out**

Comment: How does it go into the background? I'm prompted for my password which is fine, but the session is still attached. How do I get it to release back into the shell? thx